# In MPAndroidChart giving space between y-axis and line chart start and end

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am developing a line chart with some value using MPAndroidChart.
Here line chart is starting from the Y-axis and ending at the [end of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LWy7.jpg).

Please help me to give some space or add gap between starting of line and the vertical axis, and for ending also [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur01R.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a bar graph instead of a line chart.

If you make space it looks like it will not start from x-0

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the following methods

```
//Leave some space before the line
xAxis.setSpaceMin(50f);
//Leave some space after the line
xAxis.setSpaceMax(50f);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add extra space between starting of line and the vertical axis but you can get the same result by axis minimum like

```
lineChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(-2);
```